# Добавления объекта в ПКМ - Меню

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Можно ли в этом меню добавить свой префаб?

[image: Menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такой код добавляет пункт меню:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public static class Test {

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Add Player", false, 0)]
    static void AddPrefab() {
        GameObject prefab = Resources.Load("player") as GameObject;
        GameObject.Instantiate (prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Префаб для этого дожлен быть в каталоге `Assets/Resources`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если Вам необходим не пункт меню а подменю с подпунктами необходимо составить путь через `/`

```
[MenuItem("GameObject/My Prefabs/Add Player", false, 0)]
```

Comment: Стоит добавить, что вложенные пункты реализуются путем составления пути через `/`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker сейчас добавлю, спс

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а если без папки ресурсов?

Comment: @k0vpack а есть какая-то объективная причина избегать такое решение? Оно то можно без ресурсов, но там и память может утечь и вообще много ненужной головной боли.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker так при билде будет билдиться, а этот компонент может быть и не в игре

Comment: @k0vpack так называемый стриминг ассетов доступен в Pro версии из коробки https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, просто в качестве пояснения - Pro версия сейчас отличается от бесплатной только возможностью выключить встроенную аналитику Unity (сейчас редактор шлёт юнитекам все ваши действия) и их логотип при старте игры.

Comment: @k0vpack  если этот ваш код используется исключительно в редакторе (а судя по всему вопросу - это так) вы можете использовать статический класс редактора AssetDatabase - в нём есть метод LoadAssetAtPath, который позволяет загрузить ассет откуда угодно изнутри папки проекта) а вообще сами юнитеки уже очень давно советуют забыть их класс Resources, как страшный сон.

Comment: @M.Green Слышал про эту тему, но никогда не использовал, судя по api - крутая штука, но поочему unity просто не пометит его как устаревший, а в какой-нибудт 2019+ версии удалят?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, ну, AssetDatabase - это класс редактора) так что использовать его можно только для внутренних нужд и в билде нужно использовать ассет бандлы. Почему Resources не помечают устаревшим - сам задавался вопросом) у них прямо в мануале написано - Best Practices for the Resources System - Don't use it.Статья называется "A guide to AssetBundles and Resources"

Comment: @M.Green, занятно, надо будет почитать, спасибо)